# How to select all texts within an element and its children using XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath, scrapy

I want to extract the text of the following heading in scrapy, which uses XPATH:

```
<h2 id="title"><a href="https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P17-1102"><span class="acl-fixed-case">P</span>osition<span class="acl-fixed-case">R</span>ank: An Unsupervised Approach to Keyphrase Extraction from Scholarly Documents</a></h2>
```

if I use:

```
paper_title = response.xpath('//*[@id="title"]/a/descendant::*/text()').extract()
```

I will get:

```
['P', 'R']
```

Which are the inner text of two span children

if I use:

```
paper_title = response.xpath('//*[@id="title"]/a/text()').extract()
```

I will get:

```
['osition',
 'ank: An Unsupervised Approach to Keyphrase Extraction from Scholarly Documents']
```

That's the inner text of `<a>` excluding the children.

How can I extract the whole text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath,

```
string(//h2[@id="title"])
```

will return the [*string value*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of the `h2` [element](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#element-nodes) with an `id` attribute value of `"title"`,

> PositionRank: An Unsupervised Approach to Keyphrase Extraction from Scholarly Documents

as requested.

Comment: This is the correct answer to get the string value. If you want **to select** those text nodes, you'll have to use the expression `//*[@id="title"]/a//text()`

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro.

Answer (score 1):

```
response.xpath('xxxx').xpath('string()').extract()
```